# How convert Division to its multiplication equivalent

Tags: complex-multiplication

## Question

I have a division that is `x / 2` and I know that is **equivalent** to `x ⋅ 0.5` or $ \frac{x}{2}\; = x \cdot 0.5 $

- **What is the formula to get the multiplication equivalent of a division?**
- **What would be the equivalent of `x / 180`**

So a formula to get the `z`in this equation, I know `x`, I know `y` but I need **`z`**.

$$ \frac{x}{y}\; = x \cdot z $$

---

#### Context

So I know that $\frac{x}{2}\; = x \cdot 0.5$ on top of my head but I don't know how or what formula to get the $x \cdot 0.5$. So in the example above (and actually what I need know) is to know how I can get a multiplication which the result equals to `x / 180`. But I just don't wanna know for `x / 180` but for I guess that there is a formula to get that, and probably is a silly one but because of my high skills in maths this simple question is to easy for me (being sarcastic).

#### Use case

I need it for game development (but applies to any software or any computer calculation), simply put: *Computer get result from **multiplications faster than divisions***, in 99% of the time this doesn't matter because anyway the result is really quick, but in some software where performance is a problem (i.e Game Development) ins some scenario may make a difference.

Comment: $\frac x2 = x \cdot \frac 12$ and $\frac 12 = 0.5$. Generally, $\frac{x}{y} = x \cdot z$ with $z = 1/y$ (assuming that the denominator is not zero).

Comment: So, wait I am very slow in math :D . If it was for a division of 180 it would be.  $ \frac{x}{180}\; = x \cdot \frac{1}{180}\;  and \frac{1}{180}\; = 0.00555555555555555$?

Comment: Ohh yes it seems right! ok will u put that in an answer?

Comment: Note that many compilers with automatically convert the division by a constant into a multiplication (and with more precision and less error-prone than you can), see for example the discussion at https://stackoverflow.com/q/17883240/1187415. Therefore I would not do such “micro optimisations” unless you are very sure that it affects the performance of your program.

Comment: Thanks for the article, I will read that! But yes I know that, in fact my question was related to that (I mean the compiler) but not that I would use it (for the reason u just mentioned it) . But I am curious to make this calculation and I didnt know how to do it. By the way I do it with Javascript and I am not sure is javascript does convert division into multiplication

Comment: And I see that in the first answer there is actually the formula / solution u gave me :P  ``y=1/x;
for (int i=0; i<arraySize; i++) {
    a[i] = b[i] * y;
}```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10535605 | https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/363307

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use division instead of multiplication](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85303/use-division-instead-of-multiplication) – From the accepted answer: “*Maybe* if you're dividing many, many numbers by the same $y$, inverting $y$
 first and then doing a bunch of multiplications will save some cycles.”